# accessing xampp database on remote computer using visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

hi everyone i need help.

i have a simple visual basic 6 application that stores data on a xampp database. it works fine when i access my database locally using the following code:

```
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Sub main()
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySql ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Port=3306; database=MY_DATABASE; user=root; password=; option=3;"
    cn.Open
End Sub
```

now i copied the visual basic application i was using and paste it to a networked computer and did some modification on the code to access the xampp database stored on another computer. here is the code

```
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Sub main()
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySql ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=\\192.100.50.2\choco; Port=3306; database=MY_DATABASE; user=root; password=; option=3;"
    cn.Open
```

192.100.50.2 is the ip address and choco is the computer name of the computer where the xampp database was stored. my problem is i cannot access the xampp databae and i got a run error "Unknown MySQL serve host '\192.100.50.2\choey'[1106]". please help me. thanks in advanced.

Comment: Without digging into the syntax of MySQL's ODBC Driver's connection strings... it seems like you'd want the IP addrees *or* the computer name but not both.

Comment: try a ping `ping 192.100.50.2\choco`

Comment: i remember once i had a similar problem, check : (1) You have set your mysql server ip properly in your mysql conf file (2) you granted access to the user for the ip where you're running the VB code.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem, is your using "root" remotely.
1. REALLY bad idea.
Create a user just for your app.
2. Root by default can't be used remotely.
3. Use your servers name or address but not both.

Side note, it's not a XAMPP Database, it's MySQL.